# data.table returns error subsetting on column value

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I'm running into an error in data.table_1.11.4 when trying to return a column of a data table after subsetting rows based on a separate column value. For example,

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(
  x = 1:10,
  y = LETTERS[1:10],
  z = sample(c(T, F), 10, replace = T)
)

> dt
     x y     z
 1:  1 A  TRUE
 2:  2 B FALSE
 3:  3 C  TRUE
 4:  4 D FALSE
 5:  5 E FALSE
 6:  6 F  TRUE
 7:  7 G FALSE
 8:  8 H FALSE
 9:  9 I FALSE
10: 10 J  TRUE
```

When I try to subset based on logical values, I get this error

```
> dt[z == TRUE, x]
Error in setDT(list(indices = rep.int(indices__, len__), irows = irows)) : 
  object 'CexpandAltRep' not found
```

From my previous experience, and from what I've seen in the vignette, this shouldn't be the case. This appears to ONLY be the case when subsetting based on a logical value. I also get strange values when subsetting on character value "TRUE". Here are a few other instances that work correctly or return strange values

```
> # Expected
> dt[y == E, x]
Error in eval(stub[[3L]], x, enclos) : object 'E' not found
> 
> # Expected
> dt[y == "E", x]
[1] 5
> 
> # Unexpected
> dt[z == "TRUE", x]
[1]  1  3  6 10
> 
> # Unexpected
> class(dt[z == "TRUE", x])
[1] "integer"
```

Any thoughts as to what might be going on?

Edit:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.11.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1 tools_3.4.1
```

Comment: please update to the development version, if I'm not mistaken there's a bug interacting with R 3.5.0 that's now handled by not yet on CRAN

Comment: you might try writing x as c(1, ..., 10) or (maybe) x = seq(1, 10, by = 1)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yeah, I've had quite a few issues pop up with R 3.5.0 and had originally thought that to be the case. The machine I'm on now is still running 3.4.1. I wouldn't have anticipated any issues with that, but perhaps it's getting to the point where it's too far behind. I'm not sure.  

Also, why would you suggest writing x differently?

Comment: Using `dt[!!z, x]` works too

Comment: with R 3.4.3 and data.table 1.10.4 and 1.11.4 this works too

Comment: Why are the 2 cases unexpected? You filter dt for the rows where z is TRUE and you filter for the column x, which is correctly giving you 1,3,6,10, which is a bunch of integers.

Comment: @SeGa This is good to know about R 3.4.3, thank you for checking on this. I went back and checked, and I guess that I had assumed that dt[y == "E", x] would have returned a 1 column 1 row data.table rather than an integer, but it appears that that isn't the case. This, then, is also unexpected, given the [DT FAQ, 1.1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html)

Comment: with this `dt[z == "TRUE", .(x)]` you are getting the 1 row data.frame. I think its because you are accessing two column names. The FAQ says: **If 2 or more columns are required, use list() or .() instead**

Comment: @SeGa This seems slightly inconsistent to me, but that's a really good catch. For example, if I did `dt[y == "A" & x == 1, ]` I would be using two column names but still be returning a data.table. But you're right in that `dt[y == "A" & x == 1, x]` ultimately returns an integer. I can't say much more, unfortunately, as I am still waiting for our admin to update R for me. Still, it's strange that this is the case

Comment: the ALTREP error is a dead giveaway that the issue is from 3.5.0, unless you were installing development versions of R

Comment: The result of calling `DT[i, j]` will be a `data.table` when `j` inherits from `list` (e.g., `list`, `data.frame`, `data.table`). Otherwise, it returns the last value from the expression in `j`. The result of `DT[i, j, by = list(...)]` is always a `data.table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for the help. I think there was a really good discussion in the comments, so I don't want to delete this question. The issue was resolved by updating to the latest version of R.